# What type of variable works with dtype('<U95') in Python

Tags: python, pandas, variables, types

I am getting this error in my code: `"ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U95') dtype('<U95') dtype('<U95')"`. I cannot figure out what `dtype('<U95')` is. Does anybody know what form I can convert my variable so that I can return its value?

Comment: Length 95 Unicode. I believe.

Comment: Good luck debugging your error on your own.